# Group By where columns may be ambiguous

Tags: sql, group-by

Lets say I have the below table

```
SurveyID, Question 1, Question 2
--------------------------------
1       |     5    |    NULL
1       |    NULL  |    9
2       |     7    |    NULL
2       |    NULL  |    10
3       |     9    |    NULL
3       |    NULL  |    10
```

How Can I GROUP BY SurveyID to get 1 record for both Question 1 & 2?

I've tried...

```
SELECT SurveyID, [Question 1], [Question 2]
GROUP BY SurveyID, [Question 1], [Question 2]
```

Which gives me the above result, where as I'm looking for the one below.

```
SurveyID, Question 1, Question 2
--------------------------------
1       |     5    |    9
2       |     7    |    10
3       |     9    |    10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules for data retrieval are not specified, so I'm assuming you'd like to obtain maximum value for each surveyid. If that's the case, use aggregate function `max`:

```
select 
  surveyid,
  max([Question 1]) as [Question 1], 
  max([Question 2]) as [Question 2]
from yourtable
group by surveyid
```

Notice that the `GROUP BY` clause now only contains the surveyid as for each value we would like to get one record in the output.

Comment: Yes thank you, that helped group Question 1 & 2 together